# MVC 4 EditorFor/TextBoxFor and date field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

NweBee here...How would we go about displaying and editing just the date portion of a datetime field in an entry box with a specific width, using MVC 4?  We seem to be able to get the Date portion by using the Date editor template in an EditorFor, and can set the width using class="width.. in a TextBoxFor, but cannot seem to get both at the same time.

Comment: take a look at jquery ui datepicker: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the format to `@Html.TextBoxFor` like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "width-xx" })
```

You can also implement a custom Editor Template for DateTime fields following [this guide](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html) and include your custom CSS class in the new template. This solution is nice if you need the same style throughout your entire application or a specific controller.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to wrap your `@Html.EditorFor()` in a div and apply your styles by selecting the input in the containing div.

```
<div class="editorfordate">
    @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.MyDate)
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.editorfordate > input {
    width: 34px; /* or whatever you want */
}
```

A better way to do it is to implement a custom EditorFor-template so everytime you use the `@Html.EditorFor()` helper, the extra wrapper div is created automatically.